# Can I estimate submersible pump wear level?

Tags: motor, failure

My client has a rainwater tank that should never overfill. The excess water that appears several times a year is pumped out to the municipal rainwater drainage system.

Overfilling the tank can cause considerable material damage.

I have used proper radar water level sensor and controller made by Vega company that makes such things for water threatment plants etc.

There are 2 pumps (for redundancy and throughput when it is needed).

The problem is that I'm afraid that pumps may wear out at some point. There is no one around to look if everything is working, as in the water treatment plant.

I think it would be pretty good failure prevention if pumps would be just replaced every X work hours.

But maybe there is some better way? Maybe it is possible to:

- predict pump failure before it happens (and turn on some sound alarm or red light in garage)
- determine pump wear during annual inspection

My first idea is to measure pump current and I assume, that it will take a bit more current before it dies. I could use something like Lovato DMG110 multimeter with RS-485 to measure maximum current connect some kind of computer there and send some e-mail when maximum current or power threshold is reached.

<s>What do you think guys?</s> No no no... that would be opinion based.

Are there methods to determine the wear level of submersible pumps? If so - how is it done?

Comment: Perhaps two scenarios are adequate: (1):sensing no motor current when there should be current (2):sensing too much current flowing into a seized motor rotor. Be aware that sensing these failures after-the-fact may not be satisfactory if you believe that wear is the more likely failure mode.

Comment: I would measure the water flow rate - this could indicate problems with the pump itself or with the plumbing.

Comment: May be to use additional alarm sensor for water overfill.

Answer (score 1):

If you're prepared to change pumps preemptively after X hours... why not install one extra right now?

I'd install one extra pump, for redundancy.

Each pump has its own water level sensor, for redundancy.

The level sensors should not be at the same level. They should be staggered, so if there's a little bit of water, the first pump starts. If there's more, the second pump starts. If there's a lot more, the third pump starts.

This mean the first pump should wear out first.

Next, put flow sensors in the pipes. That will cover all failure modes, including stuff not related to the pump. For example if the level switch fails closed and forces the pump on when there is no water, the flow sensor will not detect flow.

If a pump is powered, and there is no flow after a few seconds, this means there is a problem.